# Inside an added jQuery function, can I know the triggered DOM object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I added a simple function:

```
$.postAndVerify = function(url)
{
    // this.event. ?
}

$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $.postAndVerify('/url');
});
```

inside in it, how do I know the caller object, i.e. #myButton? Of course I know it could be just passed:

```
$.postAndVerify = function(url, $triggeredBy)
{
}

$('#myButton').click(function() {
    $.postAndVerify('/url', $(this));
});
```

but it then would result tons of boilerplate code.

Answer (score 2):

You could make it a plugin method by assigning the method to `$.fn` instead of to `$`

```
$.fn.postAndVerify = function(url){
    console.log(this)// jQuery object 
}

$('#myButton').click(function() {
   $(this).postAndVerify('/url' );
});
```

Or you could use [`Function#bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: looks better, but hurts the clean code. "This button is able to send ajax request?"

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [call method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to pass button element as `this`

```js
$.postAndVerify = function (url) {
  console.log('this:');
  console.log(this);
};

$('#myButton').click(function () {
  $.postAndVerify.call(this, '/url');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="myButton" type="button">Click me</button>
```

Comment: its virtually the same as I mentioned as "boilerplate"